# Eloquent ORM: count() remove the select(...)

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using Eloquent ORM outside of Laravel-4 and I am building a custom Paginator.

First, I build a query using Fluent Query Builder. I want to get the number of result the query could return using `count()` and then I do a custom pagination using `take(x)` and `skip(y)`. I need to do the `count()` before the `take()->skip()->get()` so I dont fall outside of the page range. The problem is that when I use the `count()` method on the query, it seems to remove any `select` I added previously.

I isolated the problem to this simple example:

```
$query = DB::table('companies')
           ->join('countries','companies.country_id','=','countries.id')
           ->select(
               'companies.name as company_name',
               'countries.name as country_name'
           );

$nbPages = $query->count();
$results = $query->get();

//$results contains all fields of both tables 'companies' and 'countries'
```

If i invert the order of the count and get, it works fine:

```
$results = $query->get();
$nbPages = $query->count();

//$results contains only 'company_name' and 'country_name'
```

**Question:** is there a more elegant way the using something like this:

```
$tmp = clone $query;
$nbPages = $tmp->count();
$results = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not, unfortunately. Open issue on github about the problem: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/3416